# How to set DataContext to ListView ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I used to bind `ObservableCollection<ElementType>` to `ListView.ItemsSource`.
So `ItemTemplate.DataContext` was `ElementType`.

It have been working fine, till I replaced `ObservableCollection<ElementType>` with `ICollectionView` to apply visual sort to my observable collection.

Now, bindings inside of `ItemTemplate` are not detected at compile time, so my IDE shows warnings and marks my properties as unused. (But it works properly)

How can I set `ElementType` to `ItemTemplate.DataContext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `DataType` property of `DataTemplate` to `ElementType`.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ElementType}">
        ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```